# Что означает запись vector<unsigned char> vec(300)

Tags: c++, vector, stl

Что означает запись `vector<unsigned char> vec(300)`? Именно если в конструктор передается число.

Comment: Создание вектора из 300 элементов.

Comment: т.е vec.capacity()=300?

Comment: нет, `vec.size()==300`

Comment: конкретно в данном случаи   vec.size()  может быть равен  vec.capacity(), я бы сказал, что это так и есть